# Flash action logs

Tags: flash, flash-cs4

Flash files are binaries (.fla), and almost impossible to merge. Is it possible to get action logs, like "added xxx symbol", "modified xxx symbol" or rather the action stack of "undo", which could help me merge symbols of two fla files?

OTOH how do you resolve merging issues in Flash?